# Patterns or recommendations for GUI APIs

Tags: api, design-patterns, user-interface

We know things like buttons and panels are common to most languages, but are there any officially recognized and used recommendations or patterns for GUI APIs? (say, something from W3C maybe?)

Comment: are you looking for implementation patters (e.g. Observer, MVC) or standard components as you have mentioned (buttons, scrollbar...) ?

Comment: @Harald Scheirich I looking of an officially recommendation of GUI APIs that all languages should follow, for example "you should have a Button with getText and setText methods". Actually nothing for work, just curiosity. I also liked @Pangea's links.

Comment: Are you talking about GUI design or API design? There is a big difference.

Comment: @Cody Gray actually, I'm looking for any and all patterns that may exist for GUI development.. But if I need be more specific in this question, say it's for API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a collection of what you are looking for. But in each of the frameworks you will probably find patterns that are applicable. Some might be specific to the runtime architecture that the API is built for but some are fairly general like [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller), [Delegation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) or [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Here are some links I know to appropriate architecture documents

- [Apple, Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW6)
- Qt, [General](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qt-basic-concepts.html), [Model-View Programming](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/model-view-programming.html)
- Java, [Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/) (I don't know how old this is, haven't done anything using swing lately)

I have used a lot GUI frameworks over the last years and I still like the architecture that went into cocoa, it is one frameworks that implements guis in a very object oriented way. Most of the paradigms are applied consistently and repeatedly so that usually if you have figured out a way how to do things it will usually carry over to somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't think there is any official and formal patterns from standard bodies. But there is a [UI pattern catalog here.](http://ui-patterns.com/) Yahoo also maintains a [UI pattern library](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/).

Answer (score 1):

UI design is imho an art -- there's some "do this, don't do that", but not much.
Nonetheless [designing-a-gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169071/designing-a-gui) on SO
has some practical advice.
"Officially recognized": try Microsoft ?