# Application GUI Template vs Website Template

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I've searched and search and searched, for application design GUI ideas. But everytime I search all I seem to find are website templates, I never seem to find templates for building an application gui. Does anyone know of any sites that have or show examples of good application gui designs either web or client. Id like to see different examples showing layout options for different controls, tabs, buttons, data lists, menus, images, and so on. If the site also has all the graphic elements (for sale or free) that would be a plus.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also look at example sites designed with "packages", they generally have a UI designer who put them together. I am not saying you need the package, but they show you common UI layout structures:

- [ComponentArt UI](http://www.componentart.com/)
- [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage.aspx)
- [Telerik Rad Controls](http://www.telerik.com/)
- [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Downloads/NET/OnlineDemos.xml)

Answer (score 1):

I find this [site from Infragistics](http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Main) to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever considered opening up applications which have designs that you like and or think are good, and then copying those as closely as possible?

I think this is a case in which nobody will care that you took it from somebody else, because it works so much better than it otherwise would have. I think there's a couple of huge companies that have been known to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find an application on your computer that you find easy to use
2. Analyze where controls are placed on each form, how they're grouped, etc., and how they make it easy for the user to interact with them
3. Goto step 1

Also, do a search on basic GUI design practices. They should be applicable regardless of language and interface type (WinForms/web app).

Edit: Here are some articles:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90813/best-practices-principles-for-gui-design), [2](http://www.ambysoft.com/essays/userInterfaceDesign.html), [3](http://www.classicsys.com/css06/cfm/article.cfm?articleid=20)